# get_headers different result xampp localhost

Tags: php, xampp, php-7, php-5.6

I have two versions of Xampp installed on my PC. First is PHP5, second is PHP7. Both watching the same codebase (htdocs).
The urls to my local website are set in my hostfile. And have generated a local certificate which works correctly when I access my website https.

I have a piece of code which worked perfectly on PHP5 and have just the line

```
<?php 
print_r(get_headers("https://my.local.site"));
?>
```

and returns me correct a array of all the headers.
However, when I run apache with PHP7 and make the same request I have empty empty page.

What I have tried:

- I have `error_reporting(E_ALL)`
- Checked my logs for possible errors but no results.
- I also compared my php.ini, apache.conf and
  apached-xampp.conf but have no differences except the location of my
  xampp installation.
- I checked for a public website but returns me
  also an array of headers so it cant be PHP7 itself.
- Last but not at least I checked if
  get_headers is deprecated but it is part of PHP7.

Do anyone know if get_headers has a feature toggle in php.ini or other config? I am aware that the answer can be everything but made a checklist above so I am missing something...

Versions I am using:

- Controlpanel PHP 5.6 => v3.2.2
- Controlpanel PHP 7.2 => v3.2.4

Comment: You should have errors if that function fails. Are you seeing any errors in the error log? Do you have error reporting silenced by any chance?

Comment: No nothing, error_reporting is on but it returns just a 200 otherwise I should expect a 500

Comment: Try with cUrl to see if you get the same problem

Comment: @Dharman good suggestion but that is a workaround. On public internet it works, local with PHP5 of Xampp 3.2.2 it works, but PHP7 of Xampp 3.2.4 doesnt work. So it should be a setting or something but have not enough experience to know if get_headers is a module which need to be loaded, or a setting in php.ini